# Join query exception in Symfony 1.4.11/Propel 1.4.2

Tags: symfony-1.4, propel

I need to run following query:

```
SELECT 
    m.TITLE, 
    m.MOMENTOIMAGE, 
    s.CREATED_AT, 
    s.UNREAD, 
    mem.FIRSTNAME, 
    mem.LASTNAME, 
    mem.MEMBER_PHOTO,
    mem.ID 
FROM `momento_send` s,
    `send_distribution` sd,
    `momento_distribution` d,
    `momento` m,
    `member` mem
WHERE
    s.momento_idmember=6 AND
    sd.id_send=s.id AND
    sd.id_distribution=d.id AND
    d.momento_id=m.id;
```

For that, I wrote following code in Symfony 1.4 (using Propel 1.4.2) (Thanks to @j0k)

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->clearSelectColumns();
$c->addSelectColumn(MomentoPeer::TITLE);
$c->addSelectColumn(MomentoPeer::MOMENTOIMAGE);
$c->addSelectColumn(MomentoSendPeer::CREATED_AT);
$c->addSelectColumn(MomentoSendPeer::UNREAD);
$c->addSelectColumn(MemberPeer::FIRSTNAME);
$c->addSelectColumn(MemberPeer::LASTNAME);
$c->addSelectColumn(MemberPeer::MEMBER_PHOTO);
$c->addSelectColumn(MemberPeer::ID);

$c->addJoin(SendDistributionPeer::ID_SEND, MomentoSendPeer::ID, Criteria::INNER_JOIN);
$c->addJoin(SendDistributionPeer::ID_DISTRIBUTION, MomentoDistributionPeer::ID, Criteria::INNER_JOIN);
$c->addJoin(MomentoDistributionPeer::MOMENTO_ID, MomentoPeer::ID, Criteria::INNER_JOIN);
$c->addJoin(MomentoDistributionPeer::MOMENTO_IDMEMBER, MemberPeer::ID, Criteria::INNER_JOIN);

$c->add(MomentoSendPeer::MOMENTO_IDMEMBER, $memberid);

//echo $c->toString();exit;

$records = SendDistributionPeer::doSelect($c);
```

Running this code generated following error

```
[wrapped: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN momento_send ON (send_distribution.ID_SEND=momento_send.ID) INNER JOI' at line 1]
```

Can someone suggest, what is the issue.

Just to give little more info, SQL printed with **echo $c->toString();exit;** was

```
SELECT momento.TITLE, 
    momento.MOMENTOIMAGE, 
    momento_send.CREATED_AT, 
    momento_send.UNREAD, 
    member.FIRSTNAME, 
    member.LASTNAME, 
    member.MEMBER_PHOTO,
    member.ID 
FROM 
    INNER JOIN momento_send ON (send_distribution.ID_SEND=momento_send.ID) 
    INNER JOIN momento_distribution ON (send_distribution.ID_DISTRIBUTION=momento_distribution.ID) 
    INNER JOIN momento ON (momento_distribution.MOMENTO_ID=momento.ID) 
    INNER JOIN member ON (momento_distribution.MOMENTO_IDMEMBER=member.ID) 
WHERE momento_send.MOMENTO_IDMEMBER=6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `$c->setPrimaryTableName(MomentoPeer::TABLE_NAME);`

Comment: My i ask why aren't you migrating to Propel 1.6? It is a LOT easier that those annoying criteria methods. And it is backwards compatible. Meaning it still works with criteria, so you don't have to rewrite (or at least not now) the queries written with criteria. Just take a quick look here: https://github.com/propelorm/sfPropelORMPlugin

Comment: The reason is I'm worried that existing code might break and I've strict deadline of Sept 15th with lot of task remaining. Probably I'll try to migrate once product is released. However thanks for the link, I'll need it shortly.

Comment: I know this is old, but is there any reference to when Propel made these changes in its behavior. I was messing with a 1.4.x project and the OP's syntax would have worked fine, but upgrading to sfPropelOrm / Propel 1.6 introduced these errors in joined queries. I can't find any reference in Propel's documentation as to when or why they eliminated the inherent ability to self-identify the primary table's name.